# How to increase shoe size

Tags: substitute-tool, shoes

I have a shoe that I've been using for close to a year now and now it feels very tight when I put it on, is there anything I can do to enlarge the size other than getting a new one?

I want to know if there's any other thing I can do to increase the shoe size without buying anything, i.e using something that one would normally find in a house

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill water in a plastic bag and put it inside the shoes and keep the shoes in the freezer. Water expands so does your shoes.

Source: [How to increase shoe size](http://www.shoemetro.com/t-how-to-stretch-your-shoes.aspx)

Comment: If I were to ask, how certain are you of your suggestion

Comment: Adding references would be highly appreciated, so that I won't damage my shoe in the process of trying out your suggestion

Comment: http://www.shoemetro.com/t-how-to-stretch-your-shoes.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There are [many types of shoe stretchers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JO3XIM) from ~US$5 to ~US$20. There are [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QohsNMsplqI) demonstrating the use of the stretcher.

Also try thinner socks and, if you've added a cushion insole, remove it.

Finally, check your weight. Some people periodically gain and lose weight, sometimes due to water retention. This might be normal for you, or it could indicate a medical problem.

Comment: The weight / water retention hint is very good!

Comment: It's also possible for adult feet to grow without weight change &c.  I used to wear size 10 1/2 through my 30s, now I wear 12-13.

Answer (score 2):

DrMoishe's answer (i.e. use a stretcher) is correct, but I'll just add one twist to it that I got from my girlfriend that makes it free and more convenient.

Pretty much every decent size mall has a shoe repair store (at least everyone I've been to). At these stores stretching is usually a **free** service that can be done within 15 minutes while you shop or wait.